# How do I add items in the same row across records together with awk?

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to become a bit more adept with awk.   I made this .txt document, which I called food.txt, and it's irritating me that I can't figure out how to add the prices of products together.   Take this txt file for example:

```
Milk dairy 3.89
Cheese dairy 2.12
Eggs produce 1.28
Yogurt dairy 1.49
Chicken produce 2.19
Muffin pastries 0.49
Cookie pastries 0.99
```

The first row/field is the item name, second row/field is category, and last row/field is price.

I want to be able to do two things.

First, I want to add all prices in the file together, then find the average.   I should have the output of 1.78 (rounded up).

Second, I want to add the prices of all dairy products, and find the average price of the dairy products.   In this case, my output should be 2.50.

I am somewhat new to awk, so I am not sure if my txt document needs work or not. 
I made it myself just for experimentation's sake.

Here is a code I tried out, and I am not sure why it isn't working.

```c
BEGIN{ avg = 0 }

{
   total = 0
     for(i = 3; i <= NF; i++)
       if ($2 == "dairy")
       total = total +$i
   avg += total
}

END{
        print "Total Dairy Price Average =  $" avg/NR
}
```

I figured that, starting from the third field, if the second field was dairy, it would set total = total+$i.   Then avg += total.   But when I run this, it gives me something like 1.07, which is way off.

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** approach:

```
$ awk '{ cat=$(NF-1); a[cat] += $NF; sum += $NF; b[cat]++ }
       END{ for (cat in a) print cat, a[cat]/b[cat]; print "all avg", sum/NR }' file
```

The output:

```
dairy 2.5
produce 1.735
pastries 0.74
all avg 1.77857
```

Comment: I learned to use awk in script files.   Would you do me a favor and show me what your awk approach would look like as a script file?   I'm used to running things like "awk -f file.awk file.txt" You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

> First, I want to add all prices in the file together, then find the
>   average. I should have the output of 1.78 (rounded up).

Note that `NR` contains the current line number while processing the file, in the `END` clause it will tell you the total number of lines, e.g.:

```
awk '{ sum+=$3 } END { print sum, sum/NR }'
```

Or with rounded numbers:

```
awk '{ sum+=$3 } END { print sum, sum/NR }' OFMT='%.2f'
```

> Second, I want to add the prices of all dairy products, and find the
>   average price of the dairy products. In this case, my output should be
>   2.50.

You are almost not using any of the built-in goodies that awk comes with, e.g. each statement consists of `boolean_expression { actions }`. So to only act on lines where `$2 == "dairy"`:

```
awk '$2 == "dairy" { sum+=$3; count++ } END { print sum, sum/count }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP asked for some explanation, here is an attempt to do so. The answer is based on RomanPerekhrest's answer but slightly different.

```
#!/bin/awk -f

{ 
    products = $2 # Store the second field in products
    a[products] += $NF # Increment each item in the array. $NF denotes the last field. 
    total += $NF # This is the total count of the last field all together resulting in a total of:  12.45
    pr[products]++  #increment by 1 if item found in second field. For dairy this should be 3
} 
END { 
    for (products in a)  # for loop
      print products, a[products] / pr[products]  # print product name, total of products / products found
      printf("All avg: %.2f\n", total/NR); # Print average of all products. So 12.45 / 7 = 1.778571
}
```

Call the script as follows:

```
chmod u+x myawkscript.awk && ./myawkscript.awk inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Total product average

```
total_number_of_produts=`awk 'END{print NR}' filename`

awk -v t0="$total_number_of_produts" 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=sum+$NF}END{print sum/t0}' filename

output
1.777 (1.78)
```

Dairy product average

```
da=`awk '/dairy/{print NR}' filename | wc -l`

awk -v t0="$total_number_of_produts" 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=sum+$NF}END{print sum/t0}' filename 


output
2.5
```

Comment: To avoid having to loop over the file twice, notice how the other answerers used `sum/NR` in their `END` block to get the average.

Comment: Sure will improve

Comment: When you edit the post, be sure to clarify what's different about your approach than the other three, because at first glance it looks very similar. Thanks!